# Package Deployment Model, SSISDB performance slow running job through SQL Server Job Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

I currently have a ETL system running on SQL Server 2014, it used to be using individual package deployment method. We recently changed it to use the new SSISDB project deployment method.

The issue is these same packages with no other changes take roughly twice as long as the old deployment method. I understand a lot of overhead may have been from the logging that is set to 'Basic' by default for project deployments. I changed that to none with some improvement, but still far slower than our old deployment model, or even running the packages locally in visual studio.

Based on my research this is because 'None' still logs quite a bit of information to SSISDB which is causing a huge overhead. Previously we only logged errors by email with the Package Deployment Model, but with the Project Deployment Model that is not the case, and as I understand I cannot log less information in Sql Server 2014 when using this deployment model, as custom logging was only introduced in 2016.

Has anyone else had this issue and come up with any solution? Preferably a solution that isn't "switch back to Package Deployment Model" or to upgrade to 2016 which will not be in the near future. Currently I have tried and index on internal.executables from the SSISDB database. referencing this article http://www.argento-it.co.uk/ssis/ssisdb-slow/

This did not improve the situation at all, with the run time remaining the same

Comment: Try setting the logging level to performance and then look at the report from the Integration Services Catalog. Where is the time being spent?

Comment: Based on the report I see that each task and package is taking longer simply even by changing to performance, since it is logging even more to the SSISDB tables. I have identified the logging itself is the issue, as I can run these packages without SSISDB and using the old deployment model with logging turned off except for on error, and they perform great.

I just wish there was a way to actually turn off logging except for on errors, this is a serious design flaw of sql server 2014 ssis in my opinion

Comment: I have written more than a few packages using the project deployment model and can say I have not run into the situation you are describing. It's possible that the database hosting the SSISDB is under load when the packages are running and logging is simply a symptom of the load. Thee were some issues of missing indexes in the SSISDB for 2012 but those were resolved in a CU. 2014 ought to be fine